# Select Rows with a specific id and all another fields in table is 1

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I want to select a value from a table where all another value in same table is 1.

Lets say I have a field called GLOBAL_ID and in the table there is a multi same value for this GLOBAL_ID and there is another filed called IS_DELETED but with different value (1,0)

My Question is I want to select all GLOBAL_ID from Table Where (ALL) IS_DELETED have the same value (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT GLOBAL_ID
FROM tablename
GROUP BY GLOBAL_ID
HAVING MIN(IS_DELETED) = 1;
```

The condition in the `HAVING` clause filters out all `GLOBAL_ID`s with at least one `IS_DELETED = 0`.